matrix cell name not available
I try to use multipart nodes in matrix and draw lines with cell name.
Below code report error:(use pure text works fine)
 Package pgf Error: No shape named `m-1-1' is known.



See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                
l.19     \draw (m-1-1.north west)

                                -- (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-1-2.south east...

code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, matrix,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    box/.style={
        shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4
    },
}
\newcommand{\parts}[4] {
    \node[box] {\nodepart{one} #1 \nodepart{two} #2 \nodepart{three} #3 \nodepart{four} #4};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    draw,align=center] (m)
{
    \parts{AAA}{BBB}{CCC}{DDD}  &  \node{EEEEEE}; \\
};
    \draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-1-2.south east) -- (m-1-1).north west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You're overriding the standard construction of the node in the cell, so the name (m-1-1) and the name (m-1-2) are not applied i.e. even in the case where there is no multipart shape involved. Don't use \node ... ; if you want to use the (<name>-<row>-<col>) of the matrix library.

what's not proper way to draw such graphs? tabular?

It depends what you want to do. I've put some possibilities in an answer below using the matrix stuff, but a tabular would also be a possibility (perhaps with tikzmark). Personally, I'm not keen on the multipart nodes in TikZ, but maybe that's just me. They never seem to work as I want them to ;).

In a matrix of nodes, \node (<name>-<row>-<col>) {<content>}; is inserted for you. If you start the content of a cell with a backslash, this is overridden, but then the naming is obviously up to you.
More positively, here are some things you can do with either a standard \matrix or a matrix of nodes:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, matrix,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  box/.style={
    shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand {\parts} { d () mmmm } {
  \IfValueTF { #1}
  {
    \node (#1) [box] {\nodepart{one} #2 \nodepart{two} #3 \nodepart{three} #4 \nodepart{four} #5};
  }{
    \node[box] {\nodepart{one} #2 \nodepart{two} #3 \nodepart{three} #4 \nodepart{four} #5};
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  draw,align=center] 
  {
    AAA &  EEEEEE \\
  };
  \draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-1-2.south east) -- (m-1-1.north west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  draw,align=center] 
  {
    \node{AAA};  &  \node{EEEEEE}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)[column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  draw,align=center] 
  {
    \parts{AAA}{BBB}{CCC}{DDD}  &  \node{EEEEEE}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)[column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  draw,align=center] 
  {
    \parts(first){AAA}{BBB}{CCC}{DDD}  &  \node (second){EEEEEE}; \\
  };
  \draw (first.north west) -- (second.north east) -- (second.south east) -- (first.north west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

[I can't produce usable images right now due to an Okular bug.]
